# Search an array for a string and its substrings in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, search, select

I want to search an array for a certain string and(!) its substrings. For example my array is:

```
array = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he"]
```

So when I search for "hello" and its substrings (but only from the beginning: "he", "hell", "hello"), it should return

```
=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

**What I've tried so far:** Using a regular expression with the #grep and/or the #include? method like this:

```
array.grep("hello"[/\w+/])
```

or

```
array.select {|i| i.include?("hello"[/\w+/])}
```

but in both cases it only returns

```
=> ["hello"]
```

By the way, if I try `array.select{|i| i.include?("he")}` it works but like I said I want it the other way around: searching for "hello" and give me all results including the substrings from the beginning.

Comment: `e` is a substring of `hello` so `goodbye` should be in result. Or did you mean substrings only from beginning of the string? `h`,`he`,`hel`...`hello`?

Comment: yes, I mean only from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he", "he"]

# define search word:
search = "hello"

# find all substrings of this word:
substrings = (0..search.size - 1).each_with_object([]) { |i, subs| subs << search[0..i] }
#=> ["h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello"]

# find intersection between array and substrings(will exclude duplicates):
p array & substrings
#=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]

# or select array elements that match any substring(will keep duplicates):
p array.select { |elem| substrings.include?(elem) }
#=> ["hello", "hell", "he", "he"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require "abbrev"

arr = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he"]
p arr & ["hello"].abbrev.keys # => ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

Comment: That's just... beautiful

Comment: That's very cool. I'd never heard of the module [Abbrev](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html), but considering it  contains but a single method, I'm probably not alone. Those wanting more information (you can supply an optional pattern, for example) may wish to read [this](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/ruby-standard-library-abbrev/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) :

```
array = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he", "he"]
search = "hello"
array.select { |s| search[/\A#{s}/] }
# => ["hello", "hell", "he", "he"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn all the characters other than `h` in `hello` to optional.

```
> array = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he"]
> array.select{|i| i[/^he?l?l?o?/]}
=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

Comment: Could my eyes be deceiving me? Is it possible that the regex-master got it wrong? `["hl"].select{|i| i[/^he?l?l?o?/]} #=> ["hl"]`.

Comment: Cary. Then he need to put hello,he'll,hel,he inside a non capturing group. Texting from my mobile so I can't able to add that.Regex master? no. I didn't get into that level.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use a regular expression like this

```
#define Array
arr = ["hello", "hell", "goodbye", "he"]
#define search term as an Array of it's characters
search = "hello".split(//)
#=> ['h','e','l','l','o']
#deem the first as manditory search.shift
#the rest are optional ['e?','l?','l?','o?'].join
search = search.shift << search.map{|a| "#{a}?"}.join
#=> "he?l?l?o?"
#start at the beginning of the string \A
arr.grep(/\A#{search}/)
#=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the question reads:

```
array.select { |w| "hello" =~ /^#{w}/ }
  #=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array#keep_if`

```
array = ["hello", "hell", he"]
substrings = array.keep_if{|a| a.start_with?('h')}
=> ["hello", "hell", "he"]
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't it the same as `array.select{ |a| a.include?("h")}` (in my example).

Comment: Apparently it's not, because yours only returned `"hello"`, mine returned what you were looking for. And also, `include` finds all elements that contain a string. `start_with` only finds strings that start with a string

Comment: If `array = ['hat']`, `'hat'` is returned, but `'hat'` is not a substring of `'hello'`.